# Upon running the demo file that I downloaded (qtip extension in cytoscape). I am not getting any tooltip

Tags: qtip, qtip2, cytoscape.js

I'd like to use [cytoscape.js-qtip](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-qtip).
There are no tool-tips shown on mouse-over upon running the demo file

Here's the link pointing to the demo file [demo.html](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-qtip/blob/master/demo.html).

Is this extension for *qtip1* or *qtip2*?

I have already gone through this thread - [How to add tooltip on mouseover event on nodes in graph with cytoscape.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20993149/how-to-add-tooltip-on-mouseover-event-on-nodes-in-graph-with-cytoscape-js).

It would be helpful if anyone can provide me with a working example to display tool-tips on mouse-over in cytoscape using *qtip1* or *qtip2*.

Please provide links to download if there are more libraries required.

Comment: Are there any error messages in the JavaScript console?

Comment: GET http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.css [HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable 15ms]. I downloaded then css file and imported it direct through local drive. it is working now

Answer (score 1):

This was the [Error](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.css) that I encountered -  [HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable 15ms].

I had to [download](http://qtip2.com/download)  following files/libraries and import them directly through the local drive.

**- jquery.qtip.js**

**-  jquery.qtip.css**